# How do you create a cubic spline with knots in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, spline, cubic-spline

I'm trying to fit a cubic spline with three knots to some data to graph seasonality of a variable. My X data is the day number in a year (essentially range(0,366)) and the y data is the variable that is seasonal.

How do I create a cubic spline with three knots that fits to the data?

I've attempted to use:

```
    spline = sp.interpolate.interp1d(Xdata, ydata, kind='cubic')
```

And:

```
    spline = CubicSpline(Xdata, ydata, bc_type='periodic')
```

However, plotting the results from these with:

```
    plt.plot(range(0,366), spline(range(0,366)))
```

results in an exact plot of my ydata, with all the possible noise. I'm trying to create a smoothed line that is fit through the data.

My goal is to create a seasonality model that has the same y(x) value at day 0 and day 365, and a spline that bends 3 times between those values.

Comment: A slightly better way to do this:    
    from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

    spl = UnivariateSpline(Xdata, ydata)

    plt.plot(Xdata, spl(Xdata), 'g', lw=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_lsq_spline` from scipy.interpolate creates a least-squares spline fit with fixed predefined knots.